# How to override methods stated in the scope of a class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, scope, overriding

I am using Ruby 1.9.2 and Ruby on Rails 3.2.2. I have following statements:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Commentable

  acts_as_list :scope => 'category_comment_id'

  has_many :comments, :class_name => 'CategoryComment'

  # ...
end

module Commentable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    acts_as_list :scope => 'comment_id'

    has_many :comments, :class_name => 'Comment'

    # Other useful method statements...
  end

  # Other useful method statements...
end
```

In the above code I am trying to override both `acts_as_something` and `has_many` methods added to the `Category` class by the including `Commentable` module. Both methods are stated "in the scope of" `Category` so the above code does *not* work as expected: methods are not overrode.

Is it possible to override those methods? If so, how?

Comment: Try to include your module in the end of the class. As it is now, methods from your module are overwritten by class' own definitions.

Comment: @Sergio Tulentsev - Is it a bad practice to depend on the statement "position" throughout the code?

Comment: @user12882 Not necessarily, but is *is* probably bad practice to define a method (or scope—which is a method ultimately) knowing you want to use the version from a superclass/module instead. Why define it at all if it will never be used?

Comment: @Sergio Tulentsev - Furthermore, I am trying to override specific methods added by the module, not the inverse. That is, given a module that adds methods to a class, I would like to override some of those methods in that class.

Comment: @user12882 Is that not what is happening now?

Comment: @Andrew Marshall - Yes. My last comment referred to a previous comment of Sergio Tulentsev.

Comment: @user12882: I added some code to my answer. Does it help?

Comment: @Sergio Tulentsev - Yes, it does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should include your module in the end of your class definition. As it is now, methods from the module get injected before the class defines its method. This is so because ruby processes and evaluates code in the top-down manner. Therefore, a little bit later it encounters class' own definitions of the methods and overwrites those that came from the module.

So, use this knowledge according to your intention: who should override whom. If methods from the module should take dominance over those in the class, include it in the end.

### Edit

Given this code

```
require 'active_support/core_ext'

class Base
  def self.has_many what, options = {}
    define_method "many_#{what}" do
      "I am having many #{what} with #{options}"
    end
  end
end

module Commentable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    has_many :comments, class_name: 'Comment'
  end
end
```

Then

```
class Foo < Base
  include Commentable
  has_many :comments
end

# class overrides module
Foo.new.many_comments # => "I am having many comments with {}"
```

And

```
class Foo < Base
  has_many :comments
  include Commentable
end

# module overrides class 
Foo.new.many_comments # => "I am having many comments with {:class_name=>\"Comment\"}"
```

Comment: Do you know a good resource where I can read / learn more about the Ruby top-down processing you mentioned in your answer?

Comment: @user12882: not from the top of my head. I read it in some book.